# Any advice for 3 elements in a row on a mobile and 5 in a row on a desktop using Bootstrap grid system?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need some advice how to display the logos to be 3 in a row on mobile and 5 in a row on a desktop. I added classes which are hidden on mobile and it works fine but it's broken on a desktop because the logos are not centered. I tried to divide 3 separate rows and it works but it's broken on mobile because I have 5 logos on row, so on mobile appears as 3-2 3-2 3-2. If anyone has an idea how to fix it, it will be great. Thanks!

`

```
    <div class="row" style="filter: grayscale(100%); opacity: 0.6;">
            <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greywilson.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greytoyota.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greyhaven.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greyrakuten.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greymorrisons.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            </div>
        <br>
            <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greylivingsocial.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greywiley.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greybca.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greysecretsales.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greytalk-talk.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greyrya.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greylovefilm.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greybritish-heart-found.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greypots-and-co.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greyone-water.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            </div>
    </div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using Bootstrap 3.3.7.
You have to replace the `<br>` Tag with the following tag: `<div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>`

For more Details have a look at http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/css/#grid-responsive-resets

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="row" style="filter: grayscale(100%); opacity: 0.6;">
        <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greywilson.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greytoyota.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greyhaven.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greyrakuten.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greymorrisons.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        </div>
    <div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greylivingsocial.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greywiley.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greybca.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greysecretsales.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greytalk-talk.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greyrya.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greylovefilm.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greybritish-heart-found.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greypots-and-co.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centered">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/04en6oj9bira9hppfnsghibao6_logos-greyone-water.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        </div>
</div>
```